# Exception caught by widgets library A build function returned null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fairly new to flutter development. I am trying to have static header and grid card items that scroll underneath the static header, but I end up getting the error. I have tried to research no success. What am i doing wrong?

> Exception caught by widgets library  A build function returned null.
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    GridDashboard

and

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 99515 pixels on the bottom. The relevant
> error-causing widget was:    Column

[image]

my griddashboard class

```
class GridDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  var services = [
    "Home",
    "Settings",
    "Supervisor",
    "Logout",
    "Forms",
    "Messages",
    "bluetooth",
    "Check for updates",
    "Update"
  ];

  var images = [
    "images/calendar.png",
    "images/festival.png",
    "images/food.png",
    "images/image.png",
    "images/logout.png",
    "images/setting.png",
    "images/note.png",
    "images/todo.png",
    "images/map.png",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return Padding(
    //   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    //   child:
      GridView.builder(
        itemCount: services.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.4)
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Image.asset(images[index], height: 50.0, width: 50.0,),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text(services[index], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, height: 1.2),textAlign: TextAlign.center ,),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      // ),
    );
  }
}
```

my home class

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeState createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff392850),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 110,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Full Names",
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 4,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Home",
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xffa29aac),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                IconButton(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    "assets/notification.png",
                    width: 24,
                  ),onPressed: ()=>{
                },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          GridDashboard()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You removed the `return` keyword from your build function, probably by accident.

```
GridView.builder(
```

needs to be

```
return GridView.builder(
```

Otherwise your build function returns nothing and you get the errors you are getting now.

Answer (score 0):

as it says your build function was called on null which means you forgot write `return` out;
your problem is in `griddashboard` class where you wrote this

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return Padding(
    //   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    //   child:
      GridView.builder(
        itemCount: services.length
```

every time you don't write `return` in a function it shows that error , not only the build function , so you can handle it by writing `return` like this

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: services.length
```